# Terraform: Deploy Kubernetes Services with Traffic Manager Endpoint

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I need solution to add the Kubernetes services inside the Traffic manager using terraform and in order to do that I need to have a public IP address for each cluster, but it seems that IP is created under different subscription after deployment.

Tried playing with azurerm_traffic_manager_endpoint about different Types like azureEndpoints and nestedEndpoints but it seems that the script is failing with the same error listed below.

Below is my script which I want to deploy and I will share the error:

Error:

> creating/updating nestedEndpoints Endpoint "vmap-tmep" (Traffic Manager Profile "vmap-tm" / Resource Group "RG-TEST-TEST"): trafficmanager.EndpointsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="The 'resourceTargetId' property of endpoint 'vmap-tmep' is invalid or missing. The property must be specified only for the following endpoint types: AzureEndpoints, NestedEndpoints. You must have read access to the resource to which it refers."

```
# Traffic Manager Profile Resource
resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_profile" "tmp" {
  name = lower("${var.customer4letter}-${var.env3letter}-${var.locationid3letter}-${var.servicetype}-tm")
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  
  traffic_routing_method = "Weighted"

  dns_config {
    relative_name = lower("${var.customer4letter}-${var.env3letter}-${var.locationid3letter}-${var.servicetype}-tm-dns-test")
    ttl           = 100
  }

  monitor_config {
    protocol                     = "http"
    port                         = 80
    path                         = "/"
    interval_in_seconds          = 30
    timeout_in_seconds           = 9
    tolerated_number_of_failures = 3
  }
}

# Traffic Manager Endpoint Resource
resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_endpoint" "tmep" {
  name = lower("${var.customer4letter}-${var.env3letter}-${var.locationid3letter}-${var.servicetype}-tmep")
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  profile_name        = azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.tmp.name
  type                = "nestedEndpoints"
  weight              = 1000
  target_resource_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s1.id
}



################ K8S nodes pool location 1 ################

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s1" {
  name = lower("${var.customer4letter}-${var.env3letter}-${var.locationid3letter}-${var.servicetype}-k8s")
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks1"

  service_principal {
    client_id = "bsdfsdfs3b"
    client_secret = "353sdfsdfsdfsdfsd9"
  }
    role_based_access_control {
      azure_active_directory {
        managed           = true
        admin_group_object_ids = [var.group_object_id]
        tenant_id         = var.tenant_id
        azure_rbac_enabled = true
      }
        enabled = true
    
    }   

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = var.adminusername

    ssh_key {
      key_data = "${file("${var.ssh_public_key}")}"
    }
  }
auto_scaler_profile {
           new_pod_scale_up_delay           = "5s" 
           scale_down_delay_after_delete    = "10s" 
           skip_nodes_with_local_storage    = false
        }
addon_profile {
            azure_policy{
        enabled                    = true
      }
}


 default_node_pool {
          enable_auto_scaling          = true
          max_count                    = 5
          max_pods                     = 30
          min_count                    = 1
          name                         = "default"
          only_critical_addons_enabled = false
          #orchestrator_version         = "1.20.7"
          vm_size                                = "Standard_D2_v2"
          os_disk_size_gb                    = 30
}
}
```

Comment: please strip down your question code to the actually relevant parts. remove ACR etc

Comment: also, please state what you are actually trying to do. Usually you would need some ingress on k8s which would expose a public service. that you would then wire up in something like Traffic Manager - although I would actually recommend you look at Front Door instead

Comment: The code is strip down to the parts about Traffic manager, endpoint and Kubernetes cluster. There is creation of public IP address but the problem that I have its in another subscription by default created after deployment of terraform script

Comment: Hello @Igor, you need to use azure endpoint instead of nested endpoint, and as only 4 types of resources are allowed in target which are `cloud service ,app service, app service slot and public ip `. so you will have ti use public ip which is used by the aks instead of aks id in the target resource id

Comment: Hello @AnsumanBal-MT I tried that and I got error similar to nestedEndpoint. I did some checks on the portal and found that for azureEndpoints I can only add Cloud Service, App Service, App Service Slot and Public IP address.`riginal Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="The 'resourceTargetId' property of endpoint 'vmap-tmep' is invalid or missing. The property must be specified only for the following endpoint types: AzureEndpoints, NestedEndpoints. You must have read access to the resource to which it refers."`

Comment: @Igor, the public ip of the aks will be in the node resource group , so you have to reference that in the target resource id but not sure if they can be associated with traffic manager

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT using the portal I can associate the public IP address from the resource group created for the nods, Is there a way that can be done during creation of the Kubernetes services ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I followed this procedure: Checked Traffic Manager Endpoint > Clicked Add > selected AzureEndpoint and Public IP Addresses > from there I checked the resourced created associate to the nod IP address ( it looks something like kubernetes-aa39565607d6 ) clicked on that resource name related to the location and cluster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238981/discussion-between-ansumanbal-mt-and-igor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already discussed You need to change few things in your code in-order to use traffic manager for AKS.

1. You need to use `azureEndpoints` instead of `nestedEndpoints` as the
   Traffic Manager endpoint Type.
2. As there are currently four services `(Cloud Service ,App Service, App Service Slots and Public IP's)` which support the Traffic
   manager . So , you have to use the Public IP which is being used by
   the AKS .

   **You have to use the below block:**

   ```
   resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_endpoint" "tmep" {
     name = "ansumanaks-tmep"
     resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
     profile_name        = azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.tmp.name
     type                = "azureEndpoints"
     endpoint_status = "enabled"
     target_resource_id = (tolist(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s1.network_profile.0.load_balancer_profile.0.effective_outbound_ips)[0])
   }
   ```

---

**For testing I have used the below terraform Code:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg"{
    name="ansumantest"
}

# Traffic Manager Profile Resource
resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_profile" "tmp" {
  name = "ansumanaks-tm"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  
  traffic_routing_method = "Priority"

  dns_config {
    relative_name = "ansumanaks-tm-dns-test"
    ttl           = 100
  }

  monitor_config {
    protocol                     = "http"
    port                         = 80
    path                         = "/"
    interval_in_seconds          = 30
    timeout_in_seconds           = 9
    tolerated_number_of_failures = 3
  }
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "akspublicIP"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku = "Standard"
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  domain_name_label = "akstestregion"
}

# Traffic Manager Endpoint Resource
resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_endpoint" "tmep" {
  name = "ansumanaks-tmep"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  profile_name        = azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.tmp.name
  type                = "azureEndpoints"
  endpoint_status = "enabled"
  target_resource_id = (tolist(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s1.network_profile.0.load_balancer_profile.0.effective_outbound_ips)[0])
}




################ K8S nodes pool location 1 ################

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s1" {
  name = "ansumanaks-k8s"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks1"

  service_principal {
    client_id = "1dd6833b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-112c3fb4fb79"
    client_secret = "e997Q~ky5ZWHIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
    role_based_access_control {
      azure_active_directory {
        managed           = true
        tenant_id         = "72f988bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47"
        azure_rbac_enabled = true
      }
        enabled = true
    
    }   
    network_profile {
        network_plugin = "kubenet"
      load_balancer_profile {
        outbound_ip_address_ids= [azurerm_public_ip.example.id]
      }
    }

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "ansuman"

    ssh_key {
      key_data = "${file("C:/Users/ansbal/public.pub")}"
    }
  }
auto_scaler_profile {
           new_pod_scale_up_delay           = "5s" 
           scale_down_delay_after_delete    = "10s" 
           skip_nodes_with_local_storage    = false
        }
addon_profile {
            azure_policy{
        enabled                    = true
      }
}


 default_node_pool {
          enable_auto_scaling          = true
          max_count                    = 5
          max_pods                     = 30
          min_count                    = 1
          name                         = "default"
          only_critical_addons_enabled = false
          #orchestrator_version        = "1.20.7"
          vm_size                      = "Standard_D2_v2"
          os_disk_size_gb              = 30
}
}
```

**Ouputs:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

- I have Created a Public IP as well which will be used for the AKS Load balancer as when I tested with default public IP which get created while creating the AKS it gave me error as below so, to solve that I created Public IP.

> [image]

- I have removed `admin_group_object_ids = [var.group_object_id]` due
  to lack of permissions . You can use those as per your requirements.

Comment: Hello @AnsumanBa I have tested suggested scenario and deployment is completed successfully `Apply complete! Resources: 11 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.` Did the deployment with 2 PIP 2 clusters and 2 Endpoints. next test will be done with the `admin_group_object_ids = [var.group_object_id]` but I don't expect any issues

Comment: @Igor, Glad To be of help!!!